# How to verify that the user can use crontab?

Tags: shell-script, cron

I would like to verify that the specific user can use crontab or not. I want to use this verification inside the shell script.

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Do you, with "use `crontab`", mean "run cron jobs", or do you mean just "use `crontab`"?  The proper way to test whether you can run cron jobs is to try to use the `crontab` command. Well, that's would be the proper way to test whether you can use `crontab` too, of course. So, what's the issue with testing this? It seems to me that you just need to be able to test `crontab -l` with `sudo` changing you into any given user.

Answer (score 2):

```
VISUAL=true EDITOR=true crontab -e 2>/dev/null
```

This command is silent but its exit status indicates if your script (and thus the user running it) can use `crontab`.

To test another user add `-u username` (if your `crontab` supports `-u`), but this will work only if your script is privileged enough to run `crontab` on the behalf of the other user. Non-privileged script will get exit status `1` as if the other user couldn't use `crontab`. Alternatively use `sudo -u username …` (but `sudo` may *or may not* allow you to set the environment, depending on its configuration).

Disadvantages:

- Your `crontab` may or may not support `-e` (POSIX says it's optional).
- The method does not exactly verifies "that the user can use `crontab`", but rather "that the script can use `crontab` on the behalf of the user". This may or may not be what you want. If by "specific user" you mean "the user running the script" then you don't need `-u` and the method should work fine.

Advantage:

- You don't need to analyze `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny` (they are in an implementation-defined directory, if used at all); you don't need to build any logic to compose the final answer. `crontab` itself does everything for you.

Notes:

- In my Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS `crontab` checks `VISUAL` before `EDITOR`, but the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) mentions `EDITOR` only. That's why this answer sets both variables.
- It may seem `crontab -l` is better, but if the crontab doesn't exist then the command will return failure (at least this is how it behaves in my Kubuntu).
- In my Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, if the crontab doesn't exist then `VISUAL=true crontab -e` will *not* install an empty one. I'm not sure about other implementations. In case of a nonexistent crontab installation of an empty one may be a side effect.